# What is the purpose of a trivial fork of a repo?

Tags: github

Define "trivial fork": A fork that can be fast forwarded to the upstream repo. (perhaps there is an existing term)

Here is an example: the [rust repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust) has ~8k forks.
Many of these are trivial forks. The number of forks (trivial or not) seems to correlate with how popular a project is.

What is the purpose of these trivial forks?

I assume some contain merged work (ie they were not always trivial), and some were intended to have work done in them, but the forkers forgot / moved on.
But this does not seem adequate to explain all of these trivial forks.

Comment: It is easy to do and acts as a bookmark?

Comment: Who says they have to serve a purpose? How about you go and find out why they were created in the first place, so that enables you to possibly reason about their purpose. My guess (but it's just that and I also don't think your question's valid here) is that some were intended to host work that never came to be. In general, many of them probably are just unused and could be removed. In some cases, even along with the users, that signed up once and then abandoned/lost their account.

Answer (score 1):

Beside "bookmarking" (which is better done with "stars"), and misclicks (you want to see the forks, but click on "fork" by mistake, and end-up with a fork!), trivial forks represents *intent* to collaborate.

Some of those forks have branches of their own where experiment/possible patches are done.

But as long as the `master`/`main` or the original upstream repository is not involved in an active PR, those forks would remain "trivial".

Comment: This sounds reasonable